# Using the Sync Manager and Syncing Soups to Salesforce Database

Tags: smartstore, smartsync

This is my code to Push data to Salesforce Database,

```
    List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    fields.add("name");
    fields.add("note");
    fields.add("subject");
    fields.add("createdDate");


    smartStoreSDKManager = SmartStoreSDKManager.getInstance();
    UserAccountManager  user = UserAccountManager.getInstance();
    syncManager = SyncManager.getInstance( user.getCurrentUser());

    final SyncOptions options = SyncOptions.optionsForSyncUp(fields, SyncState.MergeMode.OVERWRITE);
    final SyncUpTarget target = new SyncUpTarget();

syncManager.syncUp(target,options,"Note", new SyncManager.SyncUpdateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(SyncState sync) {

    }
});
```

and im getting this exception

```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.salesforce.androidsdk.smartstore.app.SmartStoreSDKManager cannot be cast to com.salesforce.androidsdk.smartsync.app.SmartSyncSDKManager
```

What am i doing Wrong ? Can anyone Guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Error arised because i copied the salesforce library files from another project , creating a new project by using forcedroid and adding the necessary packages ie)our code package will resolve the problem.